# elasticsearch use "now" function

Tags: elasticsearch

I index a document with date value current datetime in marvel.

```
{
               "category": "27",
               "action": "BLOCKED",
               "url": "https://www.deneme.com/favicon.ico",
               "loggingdate": "26/01/2016 16:50:55",
               "clientip": "10.6.1.155"
}
```

"26/01/2016 16:59:55", its the time at the moment..
and expect get this document with this query:

```
{  
  "size":"10",
  "query":{  
    "filtered":{  
      "filter":{  
        "bool":{  
          "must":[  
            {  
              "exists":{  
                "field":"category"
              }
            },
            {  
              "term":{  
                "action":"BLOCKED"
              }
            },
            {  
              "range":{  
                "loggingdate":{  
                  "gt":"now-20s"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but returns nothing cant undertood reason..

if I get it with id:

```
{
   "_index": "webproxylog",
   "_type": "accesslog",
   "_id": "AVJ-iNlwfezuz1HM981V",
   "_version": 2,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "category": "27",
      "action": "BLOCKED",
      "url": "https://www.deneme.com/favicon.ico",
      "loggingdate": "26/01/2016 16:50:55",
      "clientip": "10.6.1.155"
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you retrieve that document from ES (via its id)? Can you update your question with that indexed document? I would like to verify the date format that was used for indexing.

Comment: It seems that loggingdate is stored as string not as date.Can you please share the mapping of your index?